# Why doesn't this assignment work outside of a function?

Tags: c, struct, initialization, variable-assignment

Here's an example of what I have going on. This first piece of code will not work.

```
typedef struct {
    char *desc;
    unsigned quantity;
} item;

item *inventory[INVENTORY_SIZE];

item thing = { "This is a thing.", 2 };
inventory[0] = &thing;  // Fail.

int main(void){
    // Code goes here.
}
```

The following code will work, however.

```
typedef struct {
    char *desc;
    unsigned quantity;
} item;

item *inventory[INVENTORY_SIZE];

item thing = { "This is a thing.", 2 };

int main(void){
    inventory[0] = &thing;  // Works.
}
```

I know I can't call functions outside of a function but that I can assign globals outside of a function. This looks like an assignment. So then why doesn't it work?

EDIT: As soon as I clicked 'post', I think I realised the answer. You can assign values in a declaration outside of a function, but only if it's a declaration. That's the answer, isn't it?

Comment: I think you misunderstand the difference between an *assignment* and *initialization*. Yours is the former. It can only be the latter if it is to be where you're doing what you're doing. It is possible to do what you want, but only as initialization, which will require rearranging some code and providing your pointer array an initialization sequence.

Comment: Re your edit (and to be read in conjunction with my answer), you don't "assign values in a declaration outside of a function", you initialise the object as part of the declaration of it. You're right that it *looks* like an assignment, except for the rather glaring fact that it *isn't* :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When we write :

```
data_type variableName = someValue;
```

It means we are first declaring **variableName** to be a variable, and of the type **data_type**. Subsequently, an assignment of a value is being done, immediately afterwards and since this is the first value assigned to  **variableName**, it's also initialising it to **someValue**.

Which is allowed. This is a special type of function, a system function, known as initialisation.

But writing

```
variableName = someValue;
```

means we are attempting to assign  **someValue** to **variableName** outside the scope of any function, and outside the scope of an initialisation.

This is not possible outside a function.

Code only executes from within called functions, with the exception of initialisation, which occurs during an initial assignment.

Answer (score 2):

This should work, if it what you're trying to accomplish:

```
item thing = { "This is a thing.", 2 };
item *inventory[INVENTORY_SIZE] = {&thing};
```

These are [definitions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) (since they are at top level scope), so the compiler will go ahead and allocate storage for them in this translation unit.

Answer (score 1):

```
item thing = { "This is a thing.", 2 };
```

is not an assignment despite what it may look like. It's actually an *initialisation* (part of a declaration) which is perfectly valid outside of a function.

On the other hand,

```
inventory[0] = &thing;
```

*is* an assignment which has to be inside a function of some description.

Bottom line, you should not apply initialisation rules to assignments.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
item thing = { "This is a thing.", 2 }
```

is an [initialization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_(programming)), which is a special case, not an assignment. This sets the initial value of a variable. Initialization is bonded with declaration, so it can reside in a file scope.

The [assignment expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)) can only reside inside a function. To put it in simple words, an assignment needs to be executed at run-time, so if it is not inside a function scope, there is no way to know *when* to execute it.

Answer (score 0):

Youre guess is right: the second example is initialisation, rather than execution of the statement. It's legal because global variables are created before the execution of the program (i.e., initial call to `main` function). Think of it like that: the command flow starts in the `main` function and it goes into all function that is called from it as they are called in the program's code. So at any moment the program is within some function, and any commands (besides initializations which are done beforehand) that do not lie within some function are automatically dead code --- the program has no means to reach them.