# Why is the external pointer causing error?

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment, external, declaration

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *a,b=9;
a=&b;
void main()
{
    //nothing here
}
```

When I run the above code in `C` I get 5 errors. They are:-

```
1) [Warning] data definition has no type or storage class

2) [Warning] type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'a' [-Wimplicit-int]

3) [Error] conflicting types for 'a'

4) [Note] previous definition of 'a' was here

5) [Warning] initialization of 'int' from 'int *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
```

The compiler is treating `*a` and `a` as different variables, why ?

But , the following program compiles without any errors :-

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int *a,b=9;
    a=&b;
}
```

Please tell me what the problem is ?

Comment: The second line is declaring a second variable of the same name of type ìnt` which is not `int *`. You can't assign to static variables in C outside of functions and the initial value.

Comment: [**Why doesn't this assignment work outside of a function?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40560468/why-doesnt-this-assignment-work-outside-of-a-function)

Comment: But shouldn't 'a' be considered as global when I wrote It outside all functions?

Comment: "When I run the above code..." You do not run the code. You already fail to compile which means you cannot run the code. Correct wording is important. You need to distinguish compilation errors from runtime errors.

Comment: Yes, `a` is considered to be global. But `int*` and `int` don't match

Answer (score 2):

For starters according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

You may not use statements like this

```
a=&b;
```

in file scopes. You may place in file scopes only declarations.

You could write for example

```
int b=9, *a = &b;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile because it is illegal to have code in the global scope - specifically your line `a=&b` is an assignment expression which is not inside any block (for example your main function).

For this exact reason your second chunk of code is legal and does work like you expect.

Answer (score 1):

> Please tell me what the problem is ?

The problem is this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *a,b=9;
a=&b;   // <----- THIS IS YOUR PROBLEM (well, one of your problems)
void main()
{
    //nothing here
}
```

you have the assignment statement

```
a=&b;
```

outside the body of any function, which isn't allowed.  You can't have *statements* at file scope.

You can have *declarations* at file scope, and the errors suggest that the compiler is trying to interpret that line as another declaration of `a`, but it's failing because a) you've already declared `a`, and b) that earlier declaration is of type `int *`, whereas the compiler is trying to declare this second `a` as an `int` (for reasons not worth going into).

A declaration like

```
int b=9, *a=&b;
```

should work, but avoid declaring things at file scope if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Lets go through the errors one by one:

### `1) [Warning] data definition has no type or storage class`

this refers to the second `a`. This tells us it was interpreted as a second variable.

### `2) [Warning] type defaults to 'int' in declaration of 'a' [-Wimplicit-int]`

This tells us the variable is implicitly declared as type int. This warning says you are missing a type. Thus you know it was read like this:

```
int *a,b=9;
int a=&b;
```

### `3) [Error] conflicting types for 'a'`

This is the error: `a` is defined as a `int *` on the first line but a `int` on the second. This is a error.

### `4) [Note] previous definition of 'a' was here`

This just tells us where the previous declaration of `a` was.

### `5) [Warning] initialization of 'int' from 'int *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]`

This is a warning since you are trying to assign a pointer to a `int` variable.

### The solution

The solution is simply to swap a and b:

```c
int b, * a=&b;
```

Or on two lines:

```c
int b;
int * a=&b;
```

This will also work, but is very ugly:

```
int *a,b=9;
int *a=&b;
```

Comment: The answer should explain why `a=&b;` didn't do what the OP intended

Comment: That's what the entire answer does right?

Comment: Only sort of. It describes what the compiler interpreted, and how to fix, but it doesn't clearly say "variables can only be assigned at creation, or in statements, but statements can only be inside functions.'

Comment: I show that "assignments" are actually interested as declarations. The rule that variables can only be assigned at creation is only a side effect.

Comment: Right. You _demonstate_, but you do not _say_.

Comment: Actually, it's perfectly valid to assign a variable after creation, as seen here: https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700OT49OXnBgqWlJWm6FjeVMvNKFCqsucCUgq2CqTUXmJ2bmJmnoalQzcVVC1EJ1QDTCAA

Comment: Yea I prefer to demonstrate these types of things instead of spelling them out. The entire point of this post was to help OP read the error to figure out the issue themselves.

Comment: It is not valid to assign a variable after definition. In your example there, you have a *declaration*, followed by a *definition* with inintialization.

Comment: It's not really different. You create (declare) a variable and later give it a value (assignment). I think this fits the definition of both terms.